# Find absolute value inequality describing the result of measurement

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

This is a problem from my homework where a sample of a quantity is $37.5\pm 1.2$ grams. And if the actual quantity is $x$, write the results as an absolute value inequality and solve for $x$.

I think I know that $36.3\le x\le 38.7$. So all I am asking for is this absolute value inequality (equation?) and maybe the logic for finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want $|x-x_0|\leq\delta$, where $x_0$ is the center of the interval and $\delta$ the half-width.